# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{((n-1)!)! (n-1)!^{n!}}{(n!)!} = 0$

Tags: limits, logarithms, factorial

I need help showing that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{((n-1)!)! (n-1)!^{n!}}{(n!)!} = 0.$$
If I take logarithm, I get
$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(\frac{((n-1)!)! (n-1)!^{n!}}{(n!)!}) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(((n-1)!)!) + n! \ln((n-1)!) - \ln((n!)!) \\ 
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(n-1)+\ln(n-3)+...+\ln(3)\\& + n! (\ln(n-1)+\ln(n-2)+...+\ln(2))\\& - \ln(n) - \ln(n-2) - ... - \ln(2),
\end{align*}$

but I don't see if that even helps.

Comment: Could Stirling's formula  $$  \ln(n!) = n\ln n -n + O(\ln n)$$ help?

Comment: You may replace $(n-1)!$ by $m$ so that $mn=n! $ and the expression under limit reduces to $\frac{m! m^{mn} } {(mn)! } $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let, $m=(n-1)!$,  Then $n!=n.(n-1)!=mn$, $m>>n$

Therefore you have $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{m!m^{mn}}{(mn)!}$$

If we take logarithm and use Stirling's formula for large $k$, $ln(k!)=k.ln(k)-k$, we would have,
$$ln(L)=\lim_{m>>n, n\to\infty} m.ln(m)-m+mn.ln(m)-mn.ln(mn)+mn$$
Now recall, $mn=n!$, and $ln(m)=ln((n-1)!)=(n-1)ln(n-1)-(n-1)$, and show with patient calculation that $$ln(L)=\lim_{m>>n, n\to\infty}=-\infty$$
Thus $L=0$

Another approach is to show that, for  $n>1$, $$ \frac{m!m^{mn}}{(mn)!} < \frac{1}{n}$$
You may use induction method for that.